# Pandas fillna throws ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

Discription: both features are in categorical dtypes. and i used this code in a different kernal of  same 
dateset was working fine, the only difference is the features are in flote64. later i have converted these feature dtypes into Categorical
because all the features in the dataset represents categories.

Below is the code:

```
AM_train['product_category_2'].fillna('Unknown', inplace =True)
AM_train['city_development_index'].fillna('Missing', inplace =True)
```

Comment: You could deal with missing values before converting into category, is a better approach.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`Series.cat.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) for add categories first:

```
AM_train['product_category_2'] = AM_train['product_category_2'].cat.add_categories('Unknown')
AM_train['product_category_2'].fillna('Unknown', inplace =True) 

AM_train['city_development_index'] = AM_train['city_development_index'].cat.add_categories('Missing')
AM_train['city_development_index'].fillna('Missing', inplace =True)
```

**Sample**:

```
AM_train = pd.DataFrame({'product_category_2': pd.Categorical(['a','b',np.nan])})
AM_train['product_category_2'] = AM_train['product_category_2'].cat.add_categories('Unknown')
AM_train['product_category_2'].fillna('Unknown', inplace =True) 

print (AM_train)
  product_category_2
0                  a
1                  b
2            Unknown
```

Comment: Very clear and explained answer with great examples.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error in a data frame while trying to get rid of all the NaNs.
I did not look too much into it, but substituting `.fillna()` for `.replace(np.nan, value)` did the trick.
Use with caution, since I am not sure `np.nan` catches all the values that are interpreted as NaN

Comment: np.nan willl not catch all the null values

Comment: @AkshayTilekar I came across that problem too, why didn't np.nan catch all of them if I may ask?

Comment: @Constantlyconfused https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803876/why-does-df-where-not-replace-all-null-values/70803926#70803926

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using fillna on a dataframe with many features when I got that error.

I preferred converting the necessary features to string first, using fillna and finally converting them back to category if needed.

```
AM_train['product_category_2'] = AM_train['product_category_2'].astype('string')
AM_train['product_category_2'].fillna('Unknown', inplace =True)
AM_train['product_category_2'] = AM_train['product_category_2'].astype('category')
```

It could also be automated, searching for all features having a dtype 'category' and converting them using the logic above.

Comment: simplest best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Load the original dataset without inplace=True, always before running the fillna secondtime.

This problem arises because, you run the code twice, so fillna cannot be performed.