# Filling np.nan entries of Float Column gives ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

After filling in nulls in all of my `category` columns using the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822041/df-fillna-throws-valueerror-fill-value-must-be-in-categories) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664948/pandas-fillna-throws-valueerror-fill-value-must-be-in-categories), I was left with many nulls in many of my float columns. I thought a simple `df.fillna(0.0, inplace = True)` would work, but, I get the error `ValueError: fill value must be in categories`. I thought this error was only for `category` type columns.

So,

I have many float columns and many category columns. I filled category columns by adding category "unknown" and then filling nulls by "unknown". Now, a simple

```
    df.fillna(0.0, inplace = True)
```

should have worked. But, it does not.

A simple way to reproduce this problem is the following:

```
     df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a"], "B":[np.nan] })
     df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category')
     df.fillna(0.0, inplace = True)
```

Please don't say that I can do:

```
     df['A'].fillna(0.0, inplace = True)
```

I have many float columns, and I can't go one by one. I have to fill all the nulls in remaining columns by 0.0 in bulk. Rest assured, all the columns are float type, but, there could be additional `category` columns, but, they don't have any nulls.

Appreciate any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that pandas doesn't allow us to replace `NaN` values in a `category` with values not in the category levels. For example, if you try `df.fillna('a')` it will work, since 'a' is present in the category levels. Interestingly, even without `NaN` in the `category` columns, pandas raises a `ValueError` (a bug maybe?). So you'll have to specify your target columns or your target `dtype` columns in order to fill `NaN`.

That said, you can easily replace `NaN` within as many float columns as you have with:

```
df.fillna({col: 0.0 for col in df.columns[df.dtypes.eq(float)]})
```

or

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq(float)] = df.select_dtypes(float).fillna(0.0)
```

Alternatively, you can just fill `NaN` in all columns other than category:

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes.ne('category')] = df.select_dtypes(exclude='category').fillna(0.0)
```

---

**Update:**

Apparently, there's an open issue already raised about it. Take a look at: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24079.

Answer (score 1):

You need to only apply fillna() on the slice that contains float columns only, then reassign. Otherwise pandas will think you might want to fillna a nonexisting value 0.0 into the categories columns, even if they do not have anything to fill.

This modification to your example will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a"], "B":[np.nan] })
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category')
#df.fillna("a", inplace = True)
df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype=="float64"]] = df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype=="float64"]].fillna(0.0)
df
```