# Pandas: replace by regex for 'category' dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to do `df.replace` for dataframe with `category` dtype.

Suppose I create dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        ['a'], ['   '], [''] 
    ],
    columns['x'],
    dtype = 'category'
)

print(df.replace(r'^\s*$', numpy.nan, regex=True))
```

The result:

```
    x
0   a
1     
2
```

E.g. values on lines 1 and 2 are not replaced (because according to documentation only strings are getting replaces).

If I remove `dtype = 'category'` - then values are replaced by NaN as expected.

I wander - what is the best way to replace blanks in whole dataframe where all columns are `category` type with NaNs?

Is it:

```
for col in df.columns:
   df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r'^\s*$', numpy.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: if the code works for you, why you ask?

Comment: Trying to find the best way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664948/pandas-fillna-throws-valueerror-fill-value-must-be-in-categories?

Comment: imo, for `python` "the best way" := "it works as expected". for me, you seem to found a best way for python.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#renaming-categories):

> Renaming categories is done by assigning new values to the
> Series.cat.categories property or by using the rename_categories()
> method

However

> Categories must also not be NaN or a ValueError is raised

Answer (score 0):

In case the number of white spaces is fixed you could alternatively do

```
df[df == '   '] = numpy.nan
```