# How to replace nan value with a date in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the beginner-friendly question, but this code does not work for me and I can't find out why. It runs without errors, but it does not fill the values.

```py
data['date'] = data['date'].replace(np.nan, '22.02.2021')
```

I tried using "fillna" function like this:

```py
data['date'].fillna('22.02.2021', inplace=True)
```

but it gives error and says that fill value must be in categories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace NaN values by Zeroes in a column of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-to-replace-nan-values-by-zeroes-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Try this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664948/pandas-fillna-throws-valueerror-fill-value-must-be-in-categories

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use pandas `pd.to_datetime()`

*https://datatofish.com/replace-nan-values-with-zeros/* :

*single column:*

`df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].fillna(value=pd.to_datetime('2/22/2021'), inplace=True)`

*entire dataframe:*

`df.fillna(value=pd.to_datetime('2/22/2021'), inplace=True)`

However because of your comment that error '*Value error : fill value must be in categories*' is thrown anyway you have to change the `dtype` of column `date` in your dataframe from `category` to i.e. `datetime64` see **[How do I convert strings in a Pandas data frame to a 'date' data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852911/how-do-i-convert-strings-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-date-data-type)** and  **[Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)**

When casting the datetime string (`22.02.2021`) using `astype()` you can skip using `pd.datetime()`

Comment: This results in: ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Comment: What is the data type of the fields in `date` ? Is it Categorical ? Because you have to change this if yes

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697773/how-to-check-the-dtype-of-a-column-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the solution.

Comment: ~~~~~ nice  ~~~~