# df.fillna() does not replace all NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I'm trying to replace `NaN` values in my dataframe using:

```
values = {'pitch_type': 'UN', 'px': -1, 'pz': -1, 'pitch_type_prev': -1,'px_prev': -1, 
          'pz_prev': -1}

df_sample.replace(np.nan, values)
```

It fills all but two values. The returned output is :

```
pitch_type       px        pz     pitch_type_prev     px_prev         pz_prev
   UN          -1.000   -1.000        -1                 NaN           -1.000
   FF           0.416    2.963        -1                 NaN           -1.000
   FF          -0.191    2.347        FF           (0.0712, 0.508]      2.963
```

Any fix for this?

Comment: ```values``` here is not a dataframe and it doesn't contain any Nan.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fillna`:

```
df_sample.fillna(values)
```

Output:

```
  pitch_type     px     pz pitch_type_prev          px_prev  pz_prev
0         UN -1.000 -1.000              -1               -1   -1.000
1         FF  0.416  2.963              -1               -1   -1.000
2         FF -0.191  2.347              FF  (0.0712, 0.508]    2.963
```

Comment: that gives me a 'fill value must be in categories' error

Comment: @Iris It looks like you're trying to fill NaNs with values that are not in the list of categories. You can add those values as categories (see e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664948/pandas-fillna-throws-valueerror-fill-value-must-be-in-categories) and then run `fillna`